# Android: How to use an external MySQL database in an app

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm trying to find the best way to connect my android app with an external MySQL database. I have looked and found lots on using PHP, but this is not the route I want to go down as it seems it would mean I need to create a website.

I am used to using JDBC with java so would preferably like to use something similar.

Comment: In order to access data from other data base you should use REST API. Here is an example: https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/android-from-scratch-using-rest-apis--cms-27117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hosting MySQL database you should already have a web server. So it should be able to run PHP.

Moreover, direct connection from your app to MySQL database on server might turn out very insecure and you should not do it this way. Best way is to stick to usual client-php-mysql approach.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to connect to external db means you can go client server approach.client is ur android app and server app communicate the external db and send the response to the client.